# How can I programmatically create nested where clauses with Zend\Db\Sql component?

Tags: zend-framework

I've tried using the following code to accomplish it, but the unnest function returns an error:

```
foreach($params as $key=>$param) {
    if(strpos($param, ',') !== false) {
        $where = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Where();

        $where->nest();
        $param_arr = explode(',', $param);

        $entered_once = 0;
        foreach($param_arr as $p) {
            $where->equalTo($key, $p);
            if($entered_once < count($param_arr)) {
                $where->or;
            }
            $entered_once++;
        }
        $where->unnest();
        $select->where($where);
    }
    else {
        $select->where(array($key => $param));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out what I'm doing wrong: I didn't realize that the nest() function returned a brand new PredicateSet and that's what I needed to call everything on. The solution is as follows:

```
foreach($params as $key=>$param) {
    if(strpos($param, ',') !== false) {
        $where = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Where();

        $predicate_set = $where->nest();
        $param_arr = explode(',', $param);

        $entered_once = 0;
        foreach($param_arr as $p) {
            $predicate_set->equalTo($key, $p);
            if($entered_once < count($param_arr)) {
                $predicate_set->or;
            }
            $entered_once++;
        }

        $predicate_set->unnest();
        $select->where($where);
    }
    else {
        $select->where(array($key => $param));
    }
}
```